# How to print AdvancedDataGrid from Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have an AdvancedDataGrid and need to export it as PDF for printing. Can you suppose me some useful links or ideas on that topic?

Note : is another better sugestion that make this possible, working with Java? Tx.

Comment: To solve my issue, i have started to use purePDF library, and it seem to be better off. http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) is a useful ActionScript 3 Open-Source PDF Library.

If you want to know how to use AlivePDF, then this website is a good starting point: [Generate PDF’s from Flex/AIR – Code Sample using AlivePDF ActionScript 3.0 Library](http://devgirl.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/generate-pdfs-from-flexair-code-sample-using-alivepdf/).

Comment: Yeah, that's what we use. I can't say it's a joy, however.

Comment: @Robusto: Agreed. But the best solution I found so far.

Comment: Yes, but i do not see a real solution how to insert an AdvancedDataGrid in a PDF file, using AlivePDF for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check the blog I have done this Component in flex 4.0
http://copyrightflex.blogspot.in/2012/11/advanced-data-grid-with-alive-pdf.html

Comment: Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.